# How to use nested class selector for tr and td?

Tags: css

If this is my html structure:

```
<tr class="editing">
   <td class="col-2"></td>
   <td class="col-2"></td>
</tr>
```

how come this nested css works fine:

```
.editing {
    padding: 1em 1.5em;      
    .col-2 {
        font-size: 11em;
    }
}
```

but this does not:

```
.editing {
    padding: 1em 1.5em;      
    td {
        font-size: 11em;
    }
}
```

I am using Chrome 114 and according to https://caniuse.com/css-nesting CSS nesting is supported. I know how to use a non-nested approach this is an exercise in using a newly supported CSS feature.

Comment: That's not CSS. That less or sass or something that gets compiled into CSS. Post the actual CSS please

Comment: @j08691 Native CSS nesting is supported by major browsers now.

Comment: @InSync Looks like I missed the memo on that one. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this article](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/css-nesting/#nesting-element-tag-names):

> HTML elements currently require the `&` symbol in front or being wrapped with `:is()`.

...and [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-nesting-1/#syntax):

> The selector of nested style rules must not start with an identifier or a functional notation.

This means you need to rewrite your second rule as:

```css
.editing {
  padding: 1em 1.5em;

  :is(td) {
    font-size: 11em;
  }
}
```

...or:

```css
.editing {
  padding: 1em 1.5em;

  & td {
    font-size: 11em;
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect response.

Answer (score -1):

nested CSS selectors are not supported (yet) in all browsers. It's not really recommended to do that right now.

You should just use them un-nested like this:

```css
.editing {
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
}

.editing .col-2 {
  font-size: 11em;
}
/* or */
.editing td {
  font-size: 11em;
}
```